# Removing DBMS_UTILITY.ANALYZE_SCHEMA(V_USER,'COMPUTE') from Oracle 11.2.0.4.180417

Tags: oracle

Is it safe to remove/comment out Procedure

```
DBMS_UTILITY.ANALYZE_SCHEMA(V_USER,'COMPUTE')
```

in Oracle  11.2.0.4.180417

Comment: This seems to be a call you are making from your application or, more likely, some maintenance tool. As we don't know why you are making that call, we can't know whether it can be removed.

Comment: There is no way you can remove that procedure - `dbms_utility` a built-in package that you can not modify

Answer (score 0):

That depends. It gathers statistics on all tables, clusters and indexes in the schema `V_USER`. So, if the statistics are up to date when the procedure is called, you can remove it. Check with

```
SELECT table_name, last_analyzed FROM all_tables WHERE owner=V_USER ORDER BY last_analyzed;
```

Normal recommendation is to call it only if a substantial amount of data has been inserted or deleted.

I wouldn't use `DBMS_UTILITY.ANALYZE_SCHEMA` but switch to the newer `DBMS_STATS .GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS`. Furthermore, I haven't used the option `COMPUTE` in years, as `ESTIMATE` is normally good enough.